# Search with flexible ranking

Tags: mongodb, search, solr, amazon-cloudsearch, azure-cognitive-search

Can any one suggest search engine that has flexible ranking calculation?

What is flexible ranking calculation?

for example I have two documents:

```
obj1 = {
 title: "new record"
 tags: [
             {value:"tag1", weight:1},
             {value:"tag2", weight:0.8},
             {value:"tag3", weight:2},
     ] 
}

obj2 = {
 title: "new record with tag1 in title"
 tags: [
             {value:"tag1", weight:0.5},
             {value:"tag2", weight:1},
             {value:"tag3", weight:0.01},
     ] 
}
```

let's assume weight for "title" property is 0.25

When I do search for "tag1" in all properties
I want search to return ranking = 1 for obj1  and ranking = 0.75 for obj2

I know Solr can do it but do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: what is the relations (formula) between 0.25 and tags.weight?

Comment: The MongoDB aggregation framework could be used to find the matching documents, calculate their score and output them ordered by the calculated score.

Comment: title has weight 0.25 constantly but tags per document may have different weights.  There is no relation between Title weight and Tags weight.

Comment: `ElasticSearch` is an option you could consider.http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-boost-field.html

Answer (score 0):

You mention weight for title but then the values you described for scores mapped directly to tag values. Not sure if you missed a detail on how these two connect.

Assuming you want the score of the title match to play a role in the overall document score in addition to boosting documents that match a particular tag or value range, you can do this with Azure Search using [scoring profiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn798928.aspx) (if you want a search-as-a-service solution), and can do it with Solr or Elasticsearch by including boosts as part of the query if you prefer to deploy and management your own infrastructure; in Elasticsearch for example there are function boosts that will allow you to use the value of a field as input to boost computation.

Comment: Title's weight is in index description (meta data) but tag's weight is a part of data.